# Qt 4.8.5 configure.exe just shows the options

Tags: c++, qt, visual-studio-2012, qt4

When trying to create a makefile for Qt 4.8.5 with the provided configure.exe, it just shows me the list of options but doesn't configure anything.
What I did:

1. Downloaded the sourcecode from here http://qt-project.org/downloads
2. Extracted it to C:/Qt/
3. Opened the VS2012 Native Tools Command Prompt (tested with x86 and x64)
4. configure.exe -prefix C:\Qt\4.8.5 -release -qt-sql-sqlite -no-multimedia -no-audio-backend -no-phonon -no-phonon-backend -no-declarative -mp -nomake examples -nomake demos -nomake docs

After this, nothing happens except the output of all possible options.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

EDIT: I couldn't see the errors because the command prompt cut them off. I saved the output with CMD > command.txt and know now, that this is a compiler configuration issue. Thank you, commenters.

Comment: Are you missing a parameter or dependency? Check if there is an error message at the top of the list of options.

Comment: Nope, no errors. It should even work if I don't set any parameters...

Comment: I try to compile the MITK (http://www.mitk.org/) and this doesn't work with Qt 5. The output is always the same: just the options are shown. My command prompt just cuts it off so I cannot really say if there are errors.

Comment: Why exactly do you need to build it yourself? Why cannot you just use the official installer?

Comment: Because there is a very nice error regarding the msvc version that was used to generate the Qt selfinstaller. I want to use MSVC 2012 and there is only a version for MSVC 2010 at the website.

Comment: @El_Mewo: have you tried to press "o" after the command?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are valid options and work for me.

Do not forget to set up your compiler properly, and also press 'o' for open source for example.